# how to package javascript html and css in one js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a chat widget on a website. The chat code has to stay independent of the website. My goal is to make one JS that has everything and Wrap that inside a IIFE. So if someone wants to implement chat on their site he/she can just include one JS and thing would work .

and then user can do 
window.chat.serverName=
Window.chat.start();

This would open a new page and the chat application would be on that

Comment: You can use various bundlers, like webpack or systemjs.

Comment: How did you end up doing it? What did you try, what worked best?

Comment: I used [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)  with various [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders) like CSS and HTML. Webpack would bundle everything for you and spit out a JS file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) with [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) and [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader), and require your css files and html files from javascript.
(e.g. `const css = require('css/foo.css');`)

[My project](https://github.com/kaitoy/reveal-console.js) is doing it.